# PHP: Getting values by date

Tags: php

Im new In PHP!.

I have an array that contains dates and vlaues. How do i get all values of 
specific date?.  EXp: I would like to get all values from year 2015. If someone Knows can guide me.

Comment: Can you post the array here or how the array looks like?

Comment: Start with [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Infiltrator : its a simple array! The keys are dates and the values are names

Comment: @u_mulder: Ok Sir!

Comment: So whats the date format?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone : (y-m-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), then check the array key substr matches the date.

```
<?php
$date = 2016;

$array = [
    '2016-01-01' => 'a',    
    '2016-01-02' => 'b',    
    '2016-12-01' => 'c',    
    '2017-01-04' => 'd',    
    '2017-01-05' => 'e',    
    '2017-01-06' => 'f',    
];

$result = array_filter($array, function ($key) use ($date) {
    return substr($key, 0, strlen($date)) == $date;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/UYaQq

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [2016-01-01] => a
    [2016-01-02] => b
    [2016-12-01] => c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array('2015-01-01' => "test1",
                '2013-02-04' => "test2",
                '2011-03-08' => "test3",
                '2016-03-08' => "test3");

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    if(date('Y',strtotime($key)) >= 2015)
        echo $value . ", ";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An Array Contains a Key and a Value. The Key in your case is the Date. And the Value is... the value

You define it like this

```
$array = array(
    Date => Value,
    AnotherDate => AnotherValue,
);
```

or since PHP5

```
$array = [
      Date => Value,
      AnotherDate => AnotherValue,
];
```

if you now look at your Array using

```
var_dump($array);
```

You'll see the date is already combined with your value and It will even show the type of value (boolean, string, integer...)

**Edit**
Anotherone was faster